# Why do I get an OutOfMemory error when Installing M2E in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I am running Eclipse Juno version for JavaEE developers. I am trying

"About Eclipse" gives me the following

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>
> Version: Juno Service Release 1
>
> Build id: 20120920-0800

M2E is not installed in this version by default, but it is available in the standard update sites.

I tried to install M2E in it by going to Help --> Install New Software, and then selecting "Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno", and searching for m2e.

It shows up there as "m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.2.0.20120903-1050"

I selected it and went on to install it (accepting the license agreement etc.)

As it downloads/installs, I get the following error

> An internal error occurred during: "Installing Software".
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Any idea why this might be happening?

This is a default Eclipse Juno install, downloaded fresh off the net. The only thing I have done in it is install the Subversive SVN plugin.

I have tried installing from the Marketplace, and also directly form the M2E update site. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to reas in config.ini of your eclipse the allocated memory size:

For 512MB RAM: -Xms256m -Xmx256m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m

For 1024MB Ram: -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

You can also avoid this memory problem by trying to install http://eclipse.org/mpc/ after that 
making the installation from there